# INDY FTP ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server

Tags: android, delphi, ftp, indy, delphi-xe5

I am developing FTP-server for **Android** on Delphi XE5. (Component IdFTPServer).
Server starts:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Server.DefaultPort := 1032;
  Server.DefaultDataPort := 1926;
  Server.Bindings.Add.IPVersion := Id_IPv4;
  //Server.ReuseSocket := rsTrue;
  Server.Active := true;
  if Server.Active = true then
  begin
    Label1.Text := GetIP+':'+IntToStr(Server.DefaultPort);
  end;
end;
```

And when client want to connect(I am using FileZilla) i get error: **ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server**.

But when I developed FTPServer for **Windows** i didn't get error and client could connect. It was worked...

Answer (score 0):

`ECONNREFUSED` means the **OS** itself, not **Indy**, refused the connection.  Indy never sees refused connections, and thus has no control over them.  For Windows servers, `ECONNREFUSED` means either the server port is not open at all, or the port's backlog of pending client connections is full at that moment.  On Android, that is likely also the case, but Android also has additional requirements, like requiring the **INTERNET** permission to be enabled (which the latest version of Indy checks for now when certain socket errors occur), and maybe also the **ACCESS_WIFI_STATE**, **CHANGE_WIFI_STATE**, and/or **ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE** permissions as well.